# "memory" destructor error C++

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

[image: Memory Error]

I recently upgraded my cocos2d-x project to the 3.0 beta2, and received this error when i try to run it. I've never seen such a vague error before and it doesn't really give me any pointers on where to start. I guess this error also applies to general C++ , since it's thrown at a vague "memory" file. All i can deduce from it is that it's a problem with something getting destroyed. Any help or pointers would be helpful :)

Comment: It's pretty clear -- code that is not in a member function or friend is calling a destructor that is protected.

Comment: i didn't know what i was expecting when i asked this, thanks for the answer though

Comment: Most likely, you are trying to manage the lifetime of an object that is either supposed to manage its own lifetime or is supposed to have its lifetime managed by some other object.

Comment: ah that's helpful, i'll try and look for that, thanks